# Conda Install if Not Installed with Dependencies

Tags: python, r, rstudio, conda, reticulate

I am trying to install Python packages in RStudio, conditional on if those packages have not been previously installed. This is for science replication, so when other researchers use this code their computers do not needlessly install packages that are already installed.

This code would be written in a R Markdown file.

```
conda install
```

Currently the code just installs packages in a R Markdown code block, that I do not run.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer you a python code that works for me. The list can include all the necessary libraries.

```
installed_list = !conda list
my_libraries = ['numpy','keras','pandas','pyswarms']
for library in my_libraries:
    librariy_exist = max([library in string for string in installed_list])
    if librariy_exist:
        print(library,'already installed')
    else:
        command_str = 'pip install '+library
        !eval $command_str
```